# How to understand "the speed of propagation of the condition of constant phase"?

Tags: optics, waves

I still can't understand that the phase can be a constant until now.

If the phase is constant, from the

$$y(x,t) = a \times \sin(phase)$$

the shape of wave will be a line parallel to x-axis.But I know that I am wrong,how to explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase of a sinusoidal wave is represented as:

$$y(x, t) = a \times \sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

So the time evolution (i.e the **part that changes with $t$**) is only the $\omega t$ term **and not** the **pure constant phase** $\phi$ term.

$\phi$ can depend on $x$ or other things but **not $t$**.

This is what is meant that the **phase is constant**.

In case you mean sth else i.e

$$y(x, t) = a \times \sin(\omega t + kx)$$

where now what was the $\phi$ term is now the $kx$ term, explicitly depending on $x$.

This description of a wave, stems from the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) (e.g for 1 dimension $x$)

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = \left(\frac{\omega}{k}\right)^2 \frac{\partial^2 y }{\partial x^2}$$

which has sinusoidal solutions of the type:

$\sin(\omega t + kx)$, $\sin(\omega t - kx)$, $\cos(\omega t + kx)$, $\cos(\omega t - kx)$

Comment: Do you know how to derive the phase velocity?While I learned it,from the textbook,I know that the phase ϕ=ω*t+k*x.In your equation,ϕ is the initial phase.

Comment: @Wisdom.Cat, see my edit